# Notify a user about a close region based on his speed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager, clregion

I'm building an app that notifies the user whenever he approaches one of my client's stores.

I want that the app will notify the user based on his speed (30km/h+ **-** 500m before, 15-24km/h **-** 200m before, 14km/h- **-** 70m before).

Currently, the `CLCircularRegion` object's radius is set to 200 and I want it to be changed based on the speed as I mentioned.

I hope you understand what I mean, if not, write in the comments your questions and I'll explain.

Does anyone have an idea how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: is your app open or in the background when you want to make this choice ?

Comment: @Wain Both open and background

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in the background because you can't change the monitored regions from there. It's probably possible to set the range to the maximum and then when the app receives an update determine the current speed and decide wether to notify the user or not, but that isn't going to be simple. So, there isn't a good solution for background usage other than to ask the user what they want and set it in advance.

If you're app is in the foreground then you can monitor location changes and update the monitored regions at any time you want based on the speed.

Comment: If I set the region radius to the maximum (500m) like you suggested, and when `didEnterRegion:` method is being called the user's speed is 10km/h (I want it to notify 70m before), how can I set that `didEnterRegion:` method will be re-called when the user is 70m away from the region?

Comment: you can't in the background, you would also need significant location change tracking and logic to check and compute it

Comment: Significant location changes tracking is enabled for my app. And you suggested: `"It's probably possible to set the range to the maximum and then when the app receives an update determine the current speed and decide wether to notify the user or not"`, but how can I do that?

Comment: you'd need to set a flag that you'd entered the region but not notified, then track the location to the centre of the region and send a local notification when you get there (then unset the flag, also unset the flag if you exit the region)

Comment: So how can I track the location to the center in the background?